# Change css based ai Inch Screen

Tags: php, css, resolution

I was ask to change a CSS according to the inch of the screen ( specifically, a css for monitors above 15 inches and the other for monitors below), using PHP. I honestly do not know how to do, as a certain -inch monitor, however, may have different resolutions.
So, I need an advice. How can I do? There is a way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: You can use CSS media queries to achieve this.

Comment: why the focus on the physical size of the screen over the screen resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the css as responsive. As you sayed same monitor above 15 inches can also use different resolution. Normally the Responsive css is used to make a view for some standard resolution (mobile, tablet, potrait, landscape, Pc small, Pc big ... )

there is a function called "device width" that can you use. But I think it works only for mobile versions, i never testet it for Monitor css.

for the media query you can use in the css somethink like:

```
 @media screen and (device-width:768px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /*your css for this resolution - this is a standard width for tablets*/
 }
```

you can also use first a standard css and than in the media query change only where you need it. Maybe something is right without media query.

Comment: thank you so much. with max/min-width or both, instead of device-width, it works also on pc. It's a good solution for the problem!